# Serialize and deserialize objects with types only known at runtime

Tags: c#, json, runtime

I'm new to using json serialization in C#.

[Redefined question]

I have a class of classes, Brains. Each nested class will inherit from IBrain interface, but not necessarily are limited to it's fields.
I am selecting a type at runtime using `typeof(Brains).GetNestedTypes().Where(brain => brain.GetInterface("IBrain") != null).ToArray();` and selecting an index in that array as the type to use.

Is there a way I can save an instance of that type to a json, and load an instance of that type from a json. If there is a different way I should be trying to solve this problem (e.g. without json), please let me know. (should I just define individual load and save functions within each nested class?)

Comment: Why not just try it out and see what happens?

Comment: JSON itself has contains no type information. Serialization functions should *NOT* be put on entities either, because serialization changes far more frequently than people expect. Just trying to handle inheritance would break all the classes that inherit from `Loadable`. Never mind that this would be a misuse of inheritance anyway. Inheritance defines an `is-a` relation. A Labrador is-a dog. The `Load` and `Save` functions should be generic methods instead, in a separate class

Comment: Unrelated: Why serialize to string and write that to file, when you can serialize to file directly?

Comment: If you really need to handle polymorphism in JSON check the docs: [Serialize Polymorphic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get all the fields to serialize - turns out System.Text.Json only serializes public properties by default. I added some code [https://learn.microsoft.com/En-Us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#example-serialize-private-fields] to get it to serialize private members too. Although the deserializing doesn't seem to work - it is a part of a separate issue and this should be fine for serializing the types only known at runtime, and returning an instance of it using the implemented interface.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
//
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;

namespace BinaryFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Brains.Brain b = new(3);
            Type btype = typeof(Brains).GetNestedTypes().Where(brain => (brain.GetInterface("IBrain") != null)).ToArray()[0];
            Loader.Save("test", b, btype);
            b.test();

            IBrain newB = Loader.Load("test", btype);
            newB.test();

        }
    }

    internal interface IBrain
    {
        public void test();
    }
    class Brains {
        [JsonIncludePrivateFields]
        public class Brain : IBrain 
        {
            private int a = 2;
            private int b;
            public int c = 4;
            public int d;

            /*
            [JsonConstructor]
            public Brain(int a, int b, int c, int d) =>
            (this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d) = (a, b, c, d);
            */

            public Brain(int B)
            {
                this.b = B;
                this.d = B + 4;
            }
            public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {c} {d}");
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
    public class JsonIncludePrivateFieldsAttribute : Attribute { }

    internal static class Loader
    {
        static void AddPrivateFieldsModifier(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
        {
            if (jsonTypeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;

            if (!jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsDefined(typeof(JsonIncludePrivateFieldsAttribute), inherit: false))
                return;

            foreach (FieldInfo field in jsonTypeInfo.Type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {
                JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo = jsonTypeInfo.CreateJsonPropertyInfo(field.FieldType, field.Name);
                jsonPropertyInfo.Get = field.GetValue;
                jsonPropertyInfo.Set = field.SetValue;

                jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Add(jsonPropertyInfo);
            }
        }

        public static void Save(string fileName, IBrain brain, Type brainType)
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IncludeFields = true,
                WriteIndented = true,
                TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
                {
                    Modifiers = { AddPrivateFieldsModifier }
                }
            };
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(brain, brainType, options));
            File.WriteAllText(fileName + ".json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(brain, options));
        }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To serialize/deserialize derived types there is [Polymorphis serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0), that adds type information that can be used to deserialize to the correct type. Note that you would typically still need to know about all derived types at compile time.

Serializing a object with a type *only* known at runtime should also work fine. The [serialize method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-8.0) just takes an `object` and a `Type`. And the `Type` can be created from the object itself.

Deserializing a completely unknown type will however be more challenging. You could still pass a `Type`-object, but that require you to somehow know what type it should be. But without any static type you cannot really use the object for anything, at least not without using reflection or `dynamic`, and neither is something I would recommend. So you would probably need to treat the json as a tree of properties, See [Json Document Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom).